# c++ Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to compile my code but once I try the InsertNode I receive a segmentation and the program crashes. Please help

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Link.h"

using namespace std;

Node *createNode (){

  Node *newNode = new Node;
  cout<<"Enter your first name"<<endl;
  cin >> newNode->firstName;
  cout<<"Enter your last name"<<endl;
  cin>>newNode->lastName;
  cout <<"Enter your ID Number"<<endl;
  cin>>newNode->idNumber;
  newNode->next=NULL;
  return newNode;
}

Node *insertNode (Node *list){
Node *NewNode = createNode();
  //Node *NewNode = new Node;
 // NewNode= createNode();

  if(list == NULL){
list=NewNode;
  }
 else{
Node *tmp = list;
while(tmp->next!=NULL)
  tmp = tmp->next;
tmp->next=NewNode;
 }
  return list;
}

Node *searchNode (Node *list){

  bool found=false;
  Node *tmp=NULL;
  int ID;

  cout << "Enter the ID you wish to search for: "<< endl;
  cin >> ID;

  if(list==NULL){
    cout << "List is empty"<<endl;
    return 0;
  }

  while(list->next!=NULL){
    if(ID == (list-> idNumber)){
      tmp=list;
      found=true;
    }

  }
  if(found=false){
    cout<<"Not found"<<endl;
    return 0;
  }

  return tmp;
}

Node *deleteNode (Node *list){

    int ID;

  if(list==NULL){
    cout <<"The list is empty"<<endl;
    return 0;
  }
  cout << "Enter the ID number you wish to delete:" << endl;
  cin >> ID;
  if(list->idNumber==ID){

    Node *temp;

    temp=list->next;

    //free(list);

    return temp;
  }

  list->next = deleteNode(list->next);

  return list;
}

void printList(Node *list){

  Node* tmp=list;

  if(tmp==NULL){
    cout<<"The list is empty"<<endl;
  }

  cout<< tmp-> firstName<<endl;
  cout << tmp->lastName<<endl;
  cout <<tmp->idNumber<<endl;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help

They are given a menu that is used to call any of these functions
added my main just to show you

```
#include "Link.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void DisplayMenu();
int main(){

  int answer=0;
  Node *NewNode = new Node;
  //NewNode = NULL;
  do{
    DisplayMenu();
    cin >> answer;
 if(answer==1){
     insertNode(NewNode);
 }
 else if(answer==2){
 deleteNode(NewNode);
 }
 else if(answer==3){
 printList(NewNode);
 }
 else if(answer==4){
 searchNode(NewNode);
 }
 else if(answer==5){
   cout << "Goodbye" << endl;
 }
  }while(answer!=5);





  return 0;


}

void DisplayMenu(){

  cout<< "1. Insert a node"<<endl;
  cout<<"2. Delete a node"<<endl;
  cout<<"3. Print List"<<endl;
  cout<<"4. Search a node-search a node and print information for a     student."<<endl;
  cout<<"5. Quit the program"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `insertNode`?

Comment: This is hardly c++ except for `new`. Could you also paste how you are calling `insert` ?

Comment: is your Node class' next member being initialized to null?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I added the rest of my program pretty much

Comment: As @Matt suggested, create a constructor  `Node() : next(NULL) { }` . This would help you. Please use a debugger to debug this.

Comment: Your program has no `main` function

Comment: The `deleteNode` function seems borked

Comment: can you post the main function?  make sure you are calling insertNode like  list = insertNode(list) and that list is initialized to NULL

Comment: Ghee Wilikers Batman! @matt I see now that I was calling the insertNode function wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, see if you can spot the difference

```
int main(){

      int answer=0;
      Node *list= NULL;    //<---- note list variable renamed to 'list' and initialized to null
      //NewNode = NULL;
      do{
        DisplayMenu();
        cin >> answer;
     if(answer==1){
         list = insertNode(list);     //<---- note added equals
     }
     else if(answer==2){
     deleteNode(list);
     }
     else if(answer==3){
     printList(list);
     }
     else if(answer==4){
     searchNode(list);
     }
     else if(answer==5){
       cout << "Goodbye" << endl;
     }
      }while(answer!=5);


      return 0;


    }
```

Comment: I really cant believe I never saw that I was returning something. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Node.next is never initialized to null.

this causes an issue in insertNode():

```
while(tmp->next!=NULL)    <---- here
  tmp = tmp->next;
```

Comment: I'm confused as to how it should be. I was trying to make it continue while the next node was not equal to NULL

Comment: @user3000195 That part (the loop) is correct. The thing is that the next node is *never* equal to NULL, since you never made it equal to NULL.

Comment: The `createNode` function does `newNode->next=NULL;`

Comment: @matt yes it does and Im really not sure why... The list is not NULL so it is skipping over the first if statement in the insertNode function. But the list should be NULL in the beginning. Im going to add my main()